# How to solve CountDistinctSlices codility question

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying the "CountDistinctSlices" codility question. I tried my best scored 30% so tried to look up on someone who did it for insights. and basically what I don't get in the answer is the use of the initialized `seen` array(and `M` for that matter) and how its being used can someone who get it kindly walk me through this code.

THis is the Answer I found without explanation

```
function solution(M, A) {
    // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
    let sum = 0;
    let front = 0;
    let back = 0;
    const seen = new Array(M+1).fill(false);
    while (front < A.length && back < A.length){
        while (front < A.length && seen[A[front]] !== true){
            sum += (front-back+1);
            seen[A[front]] = true;
            front += 1;
        }
        while (A[back] !== A[front]){
            seen[A[back]] = false;
            back += 1;
        }
        seen[A[back]] = false;
        back += 1;
    }           
    return Math.min(sum, 1000000000);
}
```

This is the full question

> An integer M and a non-empty array A consisting of N non-negative
> integers are given. All integers in array A are less than or equal to
> M.
>
> A pair of integers (P, Q), such that 0 ≤ P ≤ Q < N, is called a slice
> of array A. The slice consists of the elements A[P], A[P + 1], ...,
> A[Q]. A distinct slice is a slice consisting of only unique numbers.
> That is, no individual number occurs more than once in the slice.
>
> For example, consider integer M = 6 and array A such that:
> A[0] = 3
> A[1] = 4
> A[2] = 5
> A[3] = 5
> A[4] = 2
>
> There are exactly nine distinct slices: (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1,
> 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4) and (4, 4).
>
> The goal is to calculate the number of distinct slices.
>
> Write a function:
>
> ```
> function solution(M, A);
> ```
>
> that, given an integer M and a non-empty array A consisting of N
> integers, returns the number of distinct slices.
>
> If the number of distinct slices is greater than 1,000,000,000, the
> function should return 1,000,000,000.
>
> For example, given integer M = 6 and array A such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 3
>
> A[1] = 4
>
> A[2] = 5
>
> A[3] = 5
>
> A[4] = 2
> ```
>
> the function should return 9, as explained above.
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> ```
>     N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
>     M is an integer within the range [0..100,000];
>     each element of array A is an integer within the range [0..M].
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [count distinct slices in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847797/count-distinct-slices-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets go through the algorithm first:

- You first start from the beginning and traverse until you find a duplicate. Now you have a `range = [ back - front ]`
- The code called this range [back, front] where "back" is beginning and "front" is your moving pointer.
  How many distinct slices are there in this range? There are slices of size 1, 2, .... front - back + 1, so it is sum = `1 + 2 + 3 + ... [front - back + 1]`
- Now that you encountered a duplicate what you should do ? To understand lets take the example in the question : `[3,4,5,5,2]`. Now `front` reached `5`. Now we should bring the `back` pointer to `5` but also at the same time remove the elements `3, 4, 5` from the set because those may be present after the current front. So `back` comes to `5` which is currently pointed by `front`.

  Lets take another example `[1,2,1]` , for this `front` will reach `1` at the index `2` because that is the first duplicate found. Now where should `back` come to? It should come to `2` because that will be the position where set won't have any duplicates when you delete the elements in the set while you move the `back` pointer.
- Do this until the `front` reaches the end of the array.

**Your question about `seen`**:

How do you find a duplicate in an array? You could use either a Set or you could use a boolean array. I think the only purpose of `M` in this question is to specify the maximum value that an element in the array can have. So the code used a boolean array of size `M`.

If you use the boolean array, once you find an element of value say `v` you can just say `boolean_arr[v] = true` that means it was "seen".

Or you could use a set and create a new one when needed without having to clear your whole boolean array everytime you find a duplicate - by letting the JavaScript to handle the garbage collection - something like below ( not fully tested ):

```
function solution(M, A) {
    let sum = 0;
    let front = 0;
    let back = 0;
    let set = new Set();
    while (front < A.length) {
        while (front < A.length && !set.has(A[front])){
            sum += (front-back+1);
            set.add(A[front]);
            front += 1;
        }
        while (A[back] != A[front]) {
            set.delete(A[back]);
            back += 1;
        }
        set.delete(A[back]);
        back += 1;
    }           
    return Math.min(sum, 1000000000);
}
```

Comment: Big thanks for the clear detailed explanation, I learned something.

Comment: Your solution fails for `[1,2,1]`. According to your alg the answer 4, but it should be 5: `(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (0,1), (1,2)`. The problem is that your alg mistakenly sets back to front thereby ignoring a part of slices.

Comment: @fade2black you are right! I modified the code and also added an explanation.